# Could not find store in either context or props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am writing code with react and I just started using redux (because I require a container of sorts). However, I have been stuck at one place for a bit now. 
I get this error -

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or
>   props of "Connect(HomePage)". Either wrap the root component in a
>   , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to
>   "Connect(HomePage)".

I tried googling, and according to the [troubleshooting section](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting) of react-redux, this can be checked using these three things: 
1. Make sure you don’t have a duplicate instance of React on the page.
2. Make sure you didn’t forget to wrap your root component in < Provider>.
3. Make sure you’re running the latest versions of React and React Redux.

I have the following code that is the root (which is where the store is defined with the provider) -

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import routes from '../Routes';
import reducers from './reducers/reducers';
import actions from './actions/actions';

export default class AppRoutes extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk));
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>      
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

And this error only happens on one of the two components I have -

```
// No error when connected only in this component
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from './actions/actions';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.isAuthenticated.toString()}</h1>;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { 
    content: state.auth.content,
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.authenticated
 };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Dashboard);
```

```
// Error thrown when I try to connect this component
import React from 'react';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import Loading from './Loading';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from './actions/actions';

class HomePage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setState({ 
      loading: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    var inPage = undefined;
    if(this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      console.log('Logged in');
      inPage = <Dashboard user = {HomePage.user}/>;
    }
    else if (this.state.loading){
      console.log('Loading');
      inPage = <Loading />;
    }
    else {
      console.log('Login');
      inPage = <LoginPage />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {inPage}
      </div>
    );
  }    
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  this.setState({
    loading: false
  });
  return {
    content: state.auth.content,
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.authenticated
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(HomePage);
```

Comment: I don't think you should do a setState in the mapStateToProps, you are not in the react component context at that point. Also, I think your AppRoutes component is wrong, I usually create the store and all the redux-related variables out of a component/routes declaration.

Comment: @JeremyD I removed setState, and I switched to the setup you are talking about (moved all the redux based stuff outside). But it's still happening. It's been eating my day trying to figure out how to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is where your issue lies or not. So I may be way off base.

But, I would check to be sure you are passing down the children to your components. The way I've done this is in my App class as such:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container-fluid">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes={
  children: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default connect()(App);
```

Comment: Is this the only file you're using connect in? And the other children inherit it?

Comment: No. I use connect in several other pages as well. My store, however, is configured in a different file, in my entry point to my application. The other thing I don't see in your files is where you attach your React app to your root html document. do you have a line of code somewhere that looks like this `document.getElementById('app')`. This should appear in your root render right after your Provider setup